# My Javascript timer counting down too fast or it doesn't start onLoad

Tags: javascript, timer, onload

I have that Javascript counter:

```
var x=100;
function timerCountdown()
{
    document.getElementById('timer1').value=x;
    x--;
    t=setTimeout("timerCountdown()",1000);

    if (x<-1)
    {
        document.getElementById('timer1').value='Done!';
        clearTimeout(t);
    }   
}

function stopCounter(){
clearTimeout(t);
x=x+1;
}
```

Then I use:

```
<body onFocus='timerCountdown()' onBlur='stopCounter()'>
```

But the problem is, the countdown doesn't start when the page loads. It waits for me to click on another window and to reFocus on the window again.

So I tried this:

```
<body onLoad='timerCountdown()' onFocus='timerCountdown()' onBlur='stopCounter()'>
```

But this time, the countdown goes pretty fast. Probably because timerCOuntdown is called twice every second.

Alternatively, I could just use the onFocus and onBlur in the body tag, but I need a function to trigger the Focus upon body load. Is that possible?

Does anyone have a suggestion to solve this problem?

thanks a lot!

Comment: What about `<body onLoad='timerCountdown()' onBlur='stopCounter()'>` ?? Why do you have `onFocus='timerCountdown()'` if you have it on load?

Comment: I wonder that it is doing something at all, `c--` should throw an error.

Comment: Hi, because I want to timer to resume, once I refocus on the timer's page.

Comment: Oops my bad, it's an x instead of c. Just corrected it

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is because `setTimeout` is invoked twice, running `timerCountdown()` once for two times separately, and continually setting two `setTimeout` IDs.

This would be what you want:

```
var x = 100;
var t = 0;

function timerCountdown()
{
    if (t == 0) t = setInterval(timerCountdown, 1000);

    document.getElementById('timer1').value=x;
    x--;

    if (x < 0) 
    {
        document.getElementById('timer1').value='Done!';
        clearTimeout(t);
        ticker = 0;
    }
}

function stopCounter()
{
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = 0;
    x++;
}
```

`setInterval` is much more suited for countdown timers, and things you need to run continually since `setTimeout` only runs once and you need to keep on calling it.

*Edit:* This fixes the initial rapid triggering of the timer on Firefox.

Remove the handler from `<body onload=` and add this to the end of the script block above:

```
t = setInterval(timerCountdown, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It works, but something weird happens: for the first two seconds, the countdown goes twice as fast. I get from 100 to 98 in one second. Not quite sure why this is doing this. Do you know why it's doing that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @eric01 It's probably the browser's handling of events. Using your existing code, that issue happens on Firefox but not on Chrome. Try the suggested change that I edited in above. Note that these timers are inherently unreliable, so depending on what the browser is doing, it may speed up or slow down.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't really understand why but this has worked. Thanks a lot, regards

Comment: @eric01 You're welcome! Please do [mark it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if it has been of help to you! ;)